# Firebase Auth user is outdated when using shared user access group

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, ios-app-extension, ios-app-group

Sharing auth state between an app and its widget extension, but sometimes the auth state is not in sync. When the user signs in/out from my app, it refreshes the widget timeline, which then checks for the auth state to display the correct item. However, if I sign the user out, sometimes the call to Auth.auth().currentUser still returns a valid user.

I've confirmed that both apps are on the same user access group, and I have that app group enabled in each target's capabilities. Is there a lag between when one group updates auth state, and when another can access that state?

### Widget code

```swift
    struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
        ...
        func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<BirthdaysEntry>) -> Void) {
            if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                // fetch data from firestore
            } else {
                // logged out 
            }
        }
        ...
    }

    @main
    struct MyWidget: Widget {
        private let kind = "my_widget"
        
        init() {
            FirebaseApp.configure()
            if Auth.auth().userAccessGroup == nil {
                do {
                    try Auth.auth().useUserAccessGroup("group.com.****.******")
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
        
        var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
            StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) { entry in
                WidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
            }
        }
    }
```

### App code

```swift
    // part of main file
    class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
            FirebaseApp.configure()
            ...
            // migrate to shared keychain
            if Auth.auth().userAccessGroup == nil {
                let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
                do {
                    try Auth.auth().useUserAccessGroup("group.com.****.****") // same group
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    ...
                }
                // when we switch to app group, user will be set to nil, so
                // if user is logged in, update them in the app group
                if user != nil {
                    Auth.auth().updateCurrentUser(user!) { (err) in
                        if let err = err {
                            print(err.localizedDescription)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return true
        }
    }
    
    // in a viewmodel somewhere else
    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { [weak self] (auth, user) in
        WidgetCenter.shared.reloadTimelines(ofKind: "my_widget")
        ....
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation states:

> Note: Shared keychain does not automatically update users across apps in real time. If you make a change to a user in one app, the user must be reloaded in any other shared keychain apps before the changes will be visible.

Here's some code to get you started:

```swift
func refreshUser() {
    do {
      let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
      let sharedUser = try Auth.auth().getStoredUser(forAccessGroup: accessGroup)
      print("Current user: \(String(describing: currentUser)), shared User: \(sharedUser.uid)")
      if currentUser != sharedUser {
        updateUser(user: sharedUser)
      }
    }
    catch {
      do {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
      }
      catch {
        print("Error when trying to sign out: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      }
    }
  }
  
  func updateUser(user: User) {
    Auth.auth().updateCurrentUser(user) { error in
      if let error = error {
        print("Error when trying to update the user: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      }
    }
  }
```

The following code shows how to use this in your main SwiftUI app, but can be easily adapted to a Widget:

```swift
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
        .environmentObject(authenticationService)
    }
    .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
      print("Current phase \(phase)")
      if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        print("User: \(user.uid)")
      }
      else {
        print("No user present")
      }
      
      if phase == .active {
        // Uncomment this to refresh the user once the app becomes active
        authenticationService.refreshUser()
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is great, thanks Peter. I'll accept after I can test it later today. is it bad if I run refreshUser() from my getTimeline() function, or should I have it in a viewmodel?

Comment: I've got issues using this code. With the recent Firebase versions, currentUser == sharedUser evaluates to False, while currentUser?.uid == sharedUser?.uid evaluates to True !!

Comment: In my case I was doing some destructive actions when current and shared users were believed to not match. With the scope of your code here, you may not have a chance to realize your code logic is wrong.